# Block Virtualbox from accessing host's internet using iptables

Tags: iptables, virtualbox

I have a linux machine with its own firewall (iptables rules).

I just discovered that somehow Virtualbox is able to bypass my firewall, as the guest system is able to connect to the internet.

How can I add an iptables rule to block virtualbox from accessing internet?

Currently I'm using this rule (Virtualbox can bypass it):

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner 186 -m multiport --dports http,https -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VM can be connected on layer 3 (IP) or on layer 2 (Ethernet). Layer 3 goes through your firewall, layer 2 does not (any more by default).

If the VM is connected to a brige then you can force the bridge traffic through the firewall, see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500022/32191 Or you use `ebtables`.

I do not know whether this works with macvtap VM connections, too. So you may have to change your VM network to either bridged or layer 3 (may be called "NAT").

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use iptables, you can use the Host-only adapter.

check out my last post: [Login into a headless VirtualBox VM that has no internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014508/login-into-a-headless-virtualbox-vm-that-has-no-internet)