# Login into a headless VirtualBox VM that has no internet

Tags: virtualbox

I need to start a VirtualBox machine in headless mode and login into it. However, this VM can not have internet so I can not make ssh to this machine. Is there a way to do this login from the command line? The interface is too slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Jose Cabrera Zuniga,

try networking via the Host-only.

### Host-only Networking in VirtualBox

> A VirtualBox host-only adapter can function as a DHCP server to
>   assign ip addresses to VirtualBox virtual machines. The host machine
>   (and other virtual machines if any) can then connect to the virtual
>   machines using these ip addresses using ssh or sftp (provided an ssh
>   server is running on the virtual machine).
>
> **This does mean virtual machines using host-only can't access the outside world, but in particular, the host should be able to use ssh
>   to login to a virtual machine (with an ssh server running) and sftp to
>   transfer files between the host and the virtual machine.**

(source with images: https://condor.depaul.edu/glancast/443class/docs/vbox_host-only_setup.html)

**btw:** here are some pretty neat tricks: https://ramblings.narrabilis.com/node/374